# ng-href when populating list of links in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, angularjs

I'm working on a Chrome extension with Angular and I'm trying to use `ng-repeat` to create a list of links. Works great except I'm having issues populating the links' `href` attribute:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="#/new" href="unsafe:chrome-extension://ehklbggiaofbhgcghgnmejkpgommihdl/popup.html#/new">Add Link</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="#/bookmarks" href="unsafe:chrome-extension://ehklbggiaofbhgcghgnmejkpgommihdl/popup.html#/bookmarks">My Bookmarks</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I prevent the `unsafe:chrome-extension` stuff from being inserted? Note: I have `ng-csp` set on the root of my app.

Comment: I doubt it has something to do with Angular. In my extension when I create a link with `<a ng-href="#/new">link</a>`I get `<a ng-href="#/new" href="#/new">link</a>`. AngularJS does not try to prepend the relative link with absolute path, as far as I know. What does your tag looks like when you use href instead of ng-href. Does the link open the '#new' page as expected?

Comment: @stewie I think the concern is with the `unsafe:chrome-extension://...` part, not the duplicate attribute.

Comment: @BrandonTilley I'm not sure why you understood my comment that way. I'm fully aware of the `unsafe...` problem.

Comment: @stewie I read it a couple more times and it makes sense :) Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @stewie this only occurs for me when using ng-href inside ng-repeat. When I use ng-href elsewhere everything works as it should.

Comment: That's interesting. Let me try to reproduce it using ng-repeat. @BrandonTilley no worries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also face the same issue now. Have not found any solution.
Please check this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/YiP02I1wkNU.

Follow this, check the app.js on http://plnkr.co/edit/prTGFiheFI7GXNoDhoGT?p=preview

Code like:

> `var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);`
>
> app.config(function($compileProvider){
>     $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|**chrome-extension**):/);
>   });

It works for me.

Comment: I was getting an error under 1.2.1  - changing from `urlSanitizationWhitelist` to `aHrefSanitizationWhitelist` fixed it.