# Download lengthy data as a CSV file

Tags: node.js, angularjs, csv, download

I need to download the contents of a table shown in the view as a CSV file. I have code to format the contents of the table properly so that it can be stored as a .csv file (for example, the column separator is a comma, each record of the table is in a new line).

So, in my controller, I have the following code:

```
window.location.href = '/download?data=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.csvString);
```

I am using NodeJs for the server part. Here, I have the following route handler:

```
app.get('/download', function (req, res) {
    var data = req.query.data;

    res.attachment('data.csv');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.end(data);
});
```

This works perfectly fine. The download works and the data in the file downloaded is in perfect CSV format. No issues.

The issue arises when there are too many records in the table, that is when the data is huge. Due to this, the query parameter is really huge and I assume that it exceeds the limit and thus, the GET request returns with a 400 (Bad Request) error - note that according to my analysis, the request never reaches the server, instead I observed that the request failed using the Chrome Developer Tools. In the browser, the URL simply is `www.my_domain.com/download?data=the_lengthy_data`. That's it. The web page is blank / empty and no file is downloaded.

Thus, I wish to know how I can download the lengthy data? All examples that I came across do a GET request and thus I have to pass the lengthy data as a query parameter. Is there some other approach?

Comment: Is the CSV data generated on the front-end, sent to the server, only to be downloaded back onto the client?

Comment: @SalehenRahman Yes your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question, but from the looks of it, you are trying to "force" a download of data generated on the client. Then in this case, you could create a data URI, that has the data directly in it.

Your angular JS template:

```
<a href="data:base64,{{btoa(csvString)}}" download>Download CSV</a>
```

Your controller:

```
$scope.btoa = function (val) {
    return btoa(val);
};
```

As a result, your DOM should look like:

```
<!-- The link contains data to the CSV string "a,b,c" -->
<a href="data:text/csv;base64,YSxiLGM=" download>Download CSV</a>
```

And clicking the link downloads the CSV file.

**EDIT**

You could also force download of strings using a library called [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

So as usual, you would get the CSV, but this time, you would convert it to a BLOB.

```
var csvBlob = new Blob([$scope.csvString], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' });
```

And then, you can call FileSaver.js' `saveAs` function.

```
saveAs(csvBlob, 'mydata.csv');
```

Comment: you meant `<a ng-href="{{link}}" download> right? I mean, where in your href is the link mapped to?

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with AngularJS. I would imagine that you would set a `href` value of `$scope` to equal `'data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa($scope.csvString)`, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I followed your approach. However, I had to make some changes. Instead of `btoa()` I made use of `encodeURI()`. In addition to that, AngularJs would append `unsafe:` to the resulting reference. So, I had to follow the instructions in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/15265968/2104976 to fix the same and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer. For some reason, the `btoa` function doesn't work without you redefining the function.

Comment: This tricks generally works, In google chrome it cause a download error when data limit exceed more then 2 MB.

Answer (score 0):

[You're right about the character limit in the URL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) Generally, lengthy data is passed through **the body** as this has no character limit in theory.

However, you should avoid trying to pass a body in a GET request. [The XMLHttpRequest specs on the send method say](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method) - "If the request method is GET or HEAD, set data to null.".

So I suggest, you use a POST request and pass your parameters in the body. You'll therefore also need to rewrite the handler using app.post('download', ...) and subsequently parse request.body for those params.

Also from my understanding what you're trying to do, POST seems like the more appropriate HTTP verb as you're providing a block of data to be processed and handed back by the server.

Comment: I tried POSTing. However, no download happens. Is there anything else to do? The code is same as before, except the GET is now POST and the data is passed in the body of the POST request...

Comment: Are you using the body parser? app.use(express.bodyParser()); Then you can use req.body

Comment: bodyParser treats the body as json. Can you sending the data encoded in JSON and using something like req.body.csv

Comment: Yup - I tried that approach too where I sent the data inside an object with "content" as the key and the actual data as the value... Did not help...

Answer (score 0):

we need to change nodejs code as below. Nodejs code

```
    function downloadableFile(req, res) {
        res.attachment(document.title);
        var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
        // we read the file in buffer.
        bufferStream.end(new Buffer(document.buffer));
        return bufferStream.pipe(res);
    }
```

Angularjs do not understand the binary data. so at front end we can use third party tools like FileSaver.js'

var csvBlob = new Blob([$scope.csvString], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' });
saveAs(csvBlob, 'mydata.csv');

or we can use angularjs code like this. Angularjs  Code.

```
    downloadDocument = function (path,id,type) {

    $http.get(path).then(function (data) {
    if (data.status === 404) {
        mpToastService.showToastHeader('error', 'Error downloading document');
    } else {
        var blob = new Blob([data.data],{
        type: type + ";charset=utf-8;"
        });
        $("#" + id).attr("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        document.getElementById(id).click();
    }
    });
    }    

    //In html file, we need to include these two lines.

    <a ng-click="downloadDocument(document.path,document.id,document.mimeType)" >document.title</a>    
    <a id="document.id"></a>
```

This angular code will download the binary data at front end and then pop up download modal without any data limit in popular browsers. But generally this is not the good practice except in case of client special requirements.