# Can we Download a CSV file using Http Post?

Tags: java, angularjs, http, post, csv

So , I have some thing like this in the back end.
        response.setContentType("text/csv; name=" + fileName);
        response.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

```
    try {
        final String csvBuilder = this.reportService.tripSummaryCsvBuilder(trips);
        response.getOutputStream().write(csvBuilder.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("downloadTripSummary() - Unexpected exception: ", e);
        throw new ServerErrorException("download trip summary csv file failed");
    }
```

So, All the back end code works fine. But the only problem here is  I need to send like an ArrayList of 1000 objects to server , based on each element inside the arraylist the csv is built on the server.

If its a normal Http Get , it will works fine . But in this case, i need to use POST because I cant send 1000 objects as part of url.

I am using angular js on UI side . Could some one please assist me on how to do this ?

I have tried to use $http.post call using an ajax service in agular js, but the service is not able to pop up the window to save the file once the response is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/N5bMq7dJ4YPJrppR1PPt

Check this plunker, with fileSaver u can save as fileName.

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662404/download-lengthy-data-as-a-csv-file)