# AngularJS - dynamic link broken in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with link in sample chrome extensions I've been working on.

Looks like Chrome thinks my inline code (AngularJS bindings) is unsafe, which basically meana all dynamic links do not work.

For example, link below (inside HTML template, IndexCtrl):

```
<a href="#/edit/{{ i.id }}"> Edit </a>
```

Is render into the following, when viewing in chrome developer tools I get this:

```
<a href="unsafe:chrome-extension://abcd/index.html#/edit/1"> Edit </a>
```

Please note that the `id of /edit/1` has been bind correctly by angular - so most probably chrome has got some security feature I shall be enabling/disabling, but how?

Any suggestions please? Just FYI there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Where is the above code placed ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem - inside a controller in a template

Comment: Yes, but where is this template used ? In your Popup, in some other View, where ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem - in my index.html (file which chrome load as a started for extension) there is `ng-view` - ngRoute loads views/index.html template and here is where the link is. Should this location make difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chrome-extension` scheme is not in the default `href` whitelist, which is used when there's a binding in a `href` attribute. See [$compileProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compileProvider)'s source code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1d50663b38ba042e8d748ffa6d48cfb5e93cfd7e/src/ng/compile.js#L502) for details.

You can call `aHrefSanitizationWhitelist` with a copy of that regex, with `|chrome-extension` added, as outlined in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15265968/2630455), to prevent `unsafe:` from being prepended.

Comment: Quick one, do you know to make `ng-hide="items.length"` work under chrome? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you do the following:

1. Include CSP declaration:

   `<html lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-csp="">`
2. Use `ng-href`

   `<a ng-href="#/edit/{{ item.id }}">Link</a>`
3. Add **chrome-extensions** to the **Href Sanitization White list**

   ```
   var app = angular.module("app", []);
   app.config( function ($compileProvider) {
      $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist (/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel|chrome-extension):/);
   });
   ```